# C++ hide all function symbols except for what I specify in a shared library

Tags: c++, cmake, g++, shared-libraries

In my example code:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(__WIN32__)
    #define EXPORT extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
#elif defined(linux) || defined(__linux)
    #define EXPORT __attribute__((visibility("default"))) 
#endif


EXPORT void hello()
{
    std::cout<<"Hello world!"<<std::endl;
}


/* not exported */ void goodbye()
{
    std::cout<<"Goodbye!"<<std::endl;
}
```

compiled via options as followed:

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.9)

project(my_test)


add_library(output SHARED
    main.cpp
)

set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "g++")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS    "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -s -Wall -Wextra -std=c++17 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden")
#set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS    "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections")
#set (CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,--gc-sections  -Wl,--strip-all")
```

I see symbols rather than the `hello` function:

```
nm -D liboutput.so
```

The result:

```
                 U __cxa_atexit
                 w __cxa_finalize
                 w __gmon_start__
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
0000000000001179 T _Z5hellov
                 U _ZNSolsEPFRSoS_E
                 U _ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev
                 U _ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev
                 U _ZSt4cout
                 U _ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_
                 U _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc
```

I do not want the functions such as `_ZSt4cout` be visible from outside. My problem is not solved even if I enable the last two lines of the cmake recipe.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is correct but your program contains some undefined symbols which need to be imported from `libstdc++` at startup (e.g. `std::cout`). Linker has to insert such symbols in your library's symbol table, otherwise loader won't know that they need to be imported.

You can link against static version of STL (via `-static-libstdc++`) and apply a version script to prevent linker from exporting STL symbols from your shared library:

```
$ cat foo.map
{
  global:
    _Z3foov;  # Export only foo
  local: *;  # Hide everything else
};
$ g++ tmp.o -fPIC -shared -static-libstdc++ -Wl,--version-script=foo.map
```

Note that linking STL statically will cause code bloat.

Comment: added `set (CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "-static-libstdc++")` and then I saw far more number of function in the table (4280 lines rather than 12 lines). I see more functions such as `_ZSt21__throw_bad_exceptionv`. Any advise?

Comment: @ar2015 The linker re-exports STL symbols when you link libstdc++. I've updated the answer with ways to avoid that.

Comment: After using the map file, the number of symbols highly reduced down to 93. The example of remaining functions are `fwrite`, `getc`, `malloc`. Are they further reducible?

Comment: @ar2015 no, these are coming from Glibc which can not be linked statically to a shared library. Why do you want to hide them? These are just undefined symbols that inform runtime loader about your library dependencies.

Comment: In windows I remember that dll walker was only displaying 4 entries out of my dll.

Comment: @ar2015 I suspect you were linking against _static_ C runtime library (there's no such option on Linux).